# SQL: how to aggregate a column when groupby to ignore null and choose the latest value

Tags: sql

I got a table like this:

| date | item | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-21 | I1 | A |
| 2021-06-21 | I2 | null |
| 2021-06-22 | I1 | B |
| 2021-06-22 | I2 | null |
| 2021-06-22 | I2 | C |

I want to GROUP BY item, and let the type be the newest non-null value. (if there are different types for an item on the same date (which is not very possible), then I can use any value). In this case, the output would be:

| item | type |
| --- | --- |
| I1 | B |
| I2 | C |

I know I could do something like `sum(), count(), max(), min()` to the type, but seems not applicable to my situation, does anyone know what should I use to achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple idea is to use `row_number()` and filtering:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by item order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where type is not null
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```